# PKIX path building failed: I unable to fixed it please provide us some solution

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl

I have only .p12 file to call, its working fine when we are using by the postman, we want to call by java code, or springboot rest template

```
    KeyStore clientStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    clientStore.load(new FileInputStream("/Users/sagir/Downloads/rest-api/src/main/resources/loudcloud-test.p12"),
            "rudaN9YzjKwge5gu".toCharArray());

    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    kmf.init(clientStore, "rudaN9YzjKwge5gu".toCharArray());
    KeyManager[] kms = kmf.getKeyManagers();

    KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    trustStore.load(
            new FileInputStream(
                    "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts"),
            "changeit".toCharArray());

    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    tmf.init(trustStore);
    TrustManager[] tms = tmf.getTrustManagers();

    SSLContext sslContext = null;
    sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(kms, tms, new SecureRandom());

    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
    URL url = new URL(null, "url",
            new sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler());

    HttpURLConnection myURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

Comment: isn't the message *Input not an X.509 certificate* clear? BTW What hase the java code to do with the commandline call and the error?

Comment: sudo keytool -import -alias  test3 -file /home/mdsager/Downloads/spring-batch-demo/src/main/resources/loudcloud-test.p12 -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts              with this command i am trying to add certificate its not taking

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a [X.509 certifiate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509) for import, you have a [PKCS#12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_12)-keystore, so your command should look like:

```
keytool -importkeystore -v -srckeystore /home/mdsager/Downloads/spring-batch-demo/src/main/resources/loudcloud-test.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore  /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts -deststoretype JCEKS
```

Comment: SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No X509TrustManager implementation available               I getting this error

Comment: Looks like your certificate is not trusted or there is a certificate of a chain missing

Comment: in cmd im getting 

`Warning:
The JCEKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts -destkeystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts -deststoretype pkcs12".`



 can provide us snipped of code ..To call api using ssl